# Java BigDecimal Behaviour

Tags: java, sha1, bigdecimal

I am programming for the first time with BigDecimals.

Why is the behaviour different in follwing two programs

```
   1) BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("2.01").setScale(4);
      System.out.println(d);
      Gives me : 2.0100

  And 

   2) BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("2.01");
      d.setScale(4);
  System.out.println(d);  
      Gives me : 2.01
```

Why is this so?

Also I am having a functionality where I need to compare a row in CSV file with DB record record using some BigDecimal value. 
    DB columns have DB type as Decimal with different scales
  e.g Quantity is the column with scale defined as 4.
      when user enters value of quantity as 2 in CSV file it is retrieved as follows:

```
     BigDecimal q = new BigDecimal("2");
     which gives me big decimal with scale as 0 and precision as 1 with value as 2.
```

when  I retrieve the same value from DB using

```
      rs.getBigDecimal(54) where 54 is column index, 
  I get Big decimal with precision as 0 and scale as 4 with value as 2.0000
```

Now As I have to compare hundreds of records in CSV in all the records in DB, I was thinking of creating SHA1 value of all the records in DB and compare it with SHA1 value of contents of CSV record.
        However I don't understand how to have same string representation of two bigdecimals with same value with different precision. I know 2 and 2.0000 are not technically same for computer but for users they are same.
 So I want to have same representation of them. I also tried calculating their hashcodes but they are also different which is right as they are altogether different numbers for computer.
 So how can I have 2 as BigDecimal being converted  to 2.0000 Bigdecimal so that I can get same String representation.

this is really proving to be a blocker for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you, you've missed the assignment from the result of [setScale()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29);

```
d = d.setScale(4);
```

**Edit**

As for your second question, you can call [stripTrailingZeros()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) -

```
d = d.stripTrailingZeros();
```

Comment: Ok got it what about my second query

Comment: Do you think it is good idea to use SHA1 for comparing the contents?

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan I would suggest using a CRC if you want to do that kind of approach. SHA1 is fairly expensive to calculate, and is 160 bits long.

Comment: Can you point me to any example or link to learn about CRC. I know it is normally used to verify contents but not sure how to use it exactly. Is CRC also inexpensive in terms of speed as well?

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) is a wikipedia on that, and in general they're inexpensive to calculate. Also, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) is some documentation on a built-in CRC32 implementation.

Comment: Also do they give same output everytime for same inputs like SHA1. Sorry I am short on time as deadline is tomorrow so taking shortcut of asking you instead of reading in detail. However will definitly go through it once I am out of this

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan Yes. They just collide more often. 32 bits vs 160 bits. And a CRC is not appropriate as a cryptographic hash; however it is a one-way hash function.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal is immutable. By calling:

```
d.setScale(4);
```

You just create new instance and dont't use it.

Comment: Ok. got it What about my second query?